# Cumulative Distribution Function of Z

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, with the following probability density functions:

$f_x(x)=1/2*e^{-|x|}$, $x \in R$ and $f_y(y)=e^{-y}$, $y>0$.

Find the cumulative distribution function of $Z=min\{X^2 - 1, 2Y+1\}$.

Any help with this would be really appreciated, since I do not understand what I am supposed to do here at all. Thanks

Comment: Do you know the definition of cumulative distribution function?

Comment: @NCh yes, it's the integral of probability density function, from minus infinity to infinity

Comment: You are not given probability density function of $Z$. See hint below for the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Notice that $\min\{a, b\}  > c \iff a>c \text{ and } b>c$,  and then consider $F_Z(z) = P(Z\leq z) = 1 -P(Z>z).$